# Prolog converts string to its ascii numeric value

Tags: string, list, prolog

I'm new to prolog. I was trying to implement the following structure: `equ([v(_Val,_Name)])`.

I tried to write the following: `add(Eq,equ([]),Eq).`

I would like to use the following test: `add(equ([v(1.0,"x")]),equ([]),L).`

The expected output is: `L = equ([v(1.0,"x")]).`
The output I get: `L = equ([v(1.0,[120])]).`

For some reason, it converts the string `"x"` to it's ascii value a puts it into a list: `[120]`.

Why does it that and how can I keep it as a string?

Answer (score 1):

Standard Prolog doesn't support strings. It defines a flag, `double_quotes`, that defines the interpretation of text between double quotes. The possibly standard values of the flag are `codes`, `chars`, and `atom`. The `codes` value means that the `"x"` is interpreted as a list of character codes, which gives you the result you observed. You can confirm it with the query:

```
| ?- current_prolog_flag(double_quotes, Value).
```

It most likely will return the binding:

```
Value = codes
```

But note that in your specific example you can simply write instead:

```
add(equ([v(1.0,x)]),equ([]),L).
```

If your strings may start with an upper case letter or contain e.g. whitespace or punctuation, then an option is to enclose the text between single quotes, making it a Prolog *atom*. For example:

```
add(equ([v(1.0,'Foo bar.')]),equ([]),L).
```

You could also change the value of the flag to `atom` with the query:

```
| ?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, atom).
```

But the value `codes` is the only one truly portable across Prolog implementations. Some Prolog systems, e.g. ECLiPSe and SWI-Prolog do support a string type. Check the documentation of the system you're using.